# Creating and accessing massive ArrayLists without running out of heap space

Tags: java, memory, arraylist, heap-memory

I am trying to create an ArrayList with a size of 10 000 000 double[400] arrays as training data for my neural network, however as the list reaches a size of around 200 000 I run out of memory space (2GB allocated for the program). I need a way of creating and accessing such a list without running out of heap space.

Below I have an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Example {

    static private ArrayList<double[]> data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        data = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        double[] randomArr = new double[400];
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            randomArr = random.doubles(400, 0, 1).toArray();
            data.add(randomArr);
            if(i % 10000 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

After 370 000 iterations the program throws a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError-exception. Is there a way to fix this (without allocating more ram), and still be able to iterate through the ArrayList of data reasonably fast?

Comment: As far as I know, no. 1 `double` is 8 `bytes`. 400 `doubles` equals 3200 `bytes`. 10 million of that is 32 gigabytes. You can change your program around so it processes smaller samples so you're not storing that amount of data in memory, that would work

Comment: You probably need to use the hard drive for storage instead.

Comment: @Mark I've thought of this, but generating the dataset unfortunately takes a long time, so if I need to do it multiple times it would be to slow.

Comment: if you don't want to run out of heap space you have to use alternate ways to access your data like file

Comment: @Rudy I guess you need to benchmark which one is faster for you then, doing it multiple times in smaller samples or saving it to a file or the like.

Comment: You can try using multiple threads to accomplish your task.

Comment: Look into serializing your Example class so you can snapshot the data and not have to recreate it.

Comment: Dump the data out to a file, for example one array per line comma delimited. You simply cannot store 32GB of data in 2GB of RAM.